# Sort array without redrawing content

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js

I'm trying to sort users by `online` property:

```
var userViewModel = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.online = ko.observable(data.online);
};

var mainViewModel = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observableArray(data.users.map(function(user){
        var model = new userViewModel(user);
        model.online.subscribe(function(){
            self.users.sort(function (a, b) { return b.online() - a.online(); });
        });
        return model;
    }));

    self.users.subscribe(function(){
        console.log('users have changed');
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: users">
    Online: <div data-bind="text: online"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
</div>
```

Everything is working fine, but when changing online property, users are sorted and "users have changed" is logged. I understand it happens because I'm changing original array. What I want is - not to change original array, just display it sorted (like angular [does it](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter))

Comment: Use filter not sort. i guess if you use filter u ll get separate array with only logged in users.

Comment: I don't need only logged users, I need all, but sorted.

Comment: Yes so make two arrays one offline and one online. filter them accordingly so you ll get all of them sorted in 2 different arrays which ll give you ability to perform some actions on a particular set and also if someone goes offline then u just need to remove the element and put it in offline array and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new computed that populates a sorted list of user.

```
var mainViewModel = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observableArray(data.users.map(function(user){
        var model = new userViewModel(user);
        return model;
    }));
    self.sortedUsers = ko.computed(function(){
        var users = self.users();       
        users.sort(function (a, b) { return b.online() - a.online(); });       
        return users;
    });   
};
```

I hope it helps.